# What happen here? (Array and pointer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I was typing some code, when (After like 3 hours searching) I found this (Sorry, my main language is Spanish and I don't know how to explain this):

I have a function in another file which makes an Array to add an object while keeping the number of elements I want:

```
exports.addToArrayKeepingNum = function(ob, arr, count){
  if (arr.length < count){
    arr[arr.length] = ob;
  }else{
    var auxArr = new Array();
    var oLength = arr.length;
    for (var a = (arr.length - 1); arr.length >= count; a--){
      arr.shift();
    }
    arr[arr.length] = ob;
  }
}
```

But now, from mongoose I extract a document and try to make this:

```
Tools.addToArrayKeepingNum({ip: req.ip, datetime: Date.now()}, doc.last_visits, 15);
```

And then, Mongoose doesn't accept the document because It has been changed the schema... but If I do:

```
var arr = doc.last_visits;
Tools.addToArrayKeepingNum({ip: req.ip, datetime: Date.now()}, arr, 15);
doc.last_visits = arr;
```

It works... Why? I mean... I am passing a reference, I'm not? So It should works with the first example... I think...

If you can explain me, It would be helpful!

EDIT:

Here is the error printed in the console:

```
Thu, 27 Nov 2014 06:38:48 GMT uncaughtException Object #<Object> has no method '
save'
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save'
    at C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\TheProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\docum
ent.js:1299:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at model.pre.err.stack (C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\TheProject\node_modul
es\mongoose\lib\document.js:1281:12)
    at model._next (C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\TheProject\node_modules\mongo
ose\node_modules\hooks\hooks.js:50:30)
    at model.proto.(anonymous function) [as save] (C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Y
amireProject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\hooks\hooks.js:96:20)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\TheProject\lib\misc\l
oginUtils.js:76:17)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\TheProject\node_modul
es\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:177:8)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\TheProject\node_modules\mong
oose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\TheProject\node_modules\m
ongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:97:20)
```

"save" It's a method from Mongoose. You can see it's lose his... identity (?)

Comment: What error do you get when you do it the first way?

Comment: @BatScream Added the error to the post.

Comment: Can you post the code where you `save` the document change?

Comment: @BatScream I don't know what do you mean. After the code I use something like this, with a more elaborated next but with the error code It never enters there `doc.save(function(err){next()});`

Comment: The error indicates that `doc` has not been associated the properties of a model. There seems to be a problem how you obtain the `doc` model. The code that shows how you initialize it would be helpful.